# Do I need an extra association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-attributes

I'm building a Rails app to allow one user to request support from a group.

```
Class User
  has_many :requests

Class Request
  belongs_to :users
```

Currently, the user clicks on different links to send the request to a different subgroup.
I'd like to allow further customization by letting the user select/deselect people.

Do I need an association to make this happen?  Something like...

```
Class User
  has_many :sent_requests, class_name 'Request'
  has_many :received_requests
  has_many :requests, :through received_requests

Class Request
  belongs_to :client, class_name 'User'
  has_many :received_requests

Class ReceivedRequest
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :client
```

This seems like a pain in the ass.  Can I just
 - create a @users instance variable in the request#new controller action, without any association
 - pass it to the view, have the form display checkboxes
 - have the user uncheck people
 - somehow pass that variable back to the create action

I guess the more general question is, how do I decide I need to add an association?

Finally, could this be a case where I need to use nested resources?

Thanks for your help.  I'm new at this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an association here since you'll want to store which users are linked with specific requests in the database. The association is the proper way to store these kinds of relationships with rails.

Associations are actually very easy to manage if they're set up properly. I don't see any advantage in using nested resources in this case.

On alternative would be to just use a modified HABTM association but include an attribute in the join model to indicate which user owns the request and which user is receiving it.

```
Class User
  has_many :requests, through: :user_requests
  has_many :user_requests

Class Request
  has_many :users, through: :user_requests
  has_many :user_requests

Class UserRequest
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :request
```

In UserRequest have a an attribute called :owner. Set this to true for the Join between the User issuing the request and the Request object. The remainder of the Users associated with that request will be receiving it.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.